Dynamically set PaintEventArgs on Label
Updating Question to have more info
I am trying to set the colour of some circles based on the values of data within an object.
I have the following Class:
public class Monster {
    public int Stat1 {get; set;}
    public int Stat2 {get; set;}
    public int Stat3 {get; set;}
}

Within a Method of my Form Class I set the Values for stats 1,2,3:
namespace Game
{
    public partial class MonsterModel : Form
    {
        public PokedexModel(string pokemon, List<PokeAPI> p)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void PopulateData(string name)
        {
            Monster m = new Monster();
            m = LoadStats(name);
        }
    }
}

From here I can access the stats by calling m.Stat1 etc.
Now I have the following three Labels using the Paint event:
        private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, 0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

        private void label2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, 0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

        private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, 0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:
        private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m.Stat1 < 100)
            SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, 0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

I have a couple of ways of doing this.
Option 1 - Instantiate m at a higher level:
namespace Game
{
    public partial class MonsterModel : Form
    {
        Monster m = new Monster();
        public PokedexModel(string pokemon, List<PokeAPI> p)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void PopulateData(string name)
        {
            m = LoadStats(name);
        }
    }
}

Option 2 - Update PopulateData():
        private async void PopulateData(string name)
        {
            m = LoadStats(name);
            if (m.Stat1 < 100) {
            label1.Paint += (sender, e) =>
            {
                SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, 0, 0, 30, 30);
            };

            label1.Invalidate();
        }
}



Is there a better way of doing this?

Where is this number coming from? Does it represent the content of the text of this Control? In that case, does it represent all the content? -- Add the information to the body of the question -- Not clear why you're referring to PaintEventArgs, when you need to create a Brush based on some criteria (BTW, SolidBrush is disposable, and anti-aliasing is mandatory here)

Hi Jimi, I have updated the question to contain more information that hopefully helps

You didn't make it that much better. My understanding was that you have 3 Controls (Labels) that need to show one of three colors, depending on the value of an associated property (the [Monster].Stat(x) property). Is that the case? If it is, then remove the clutter and just say that -- You need to specify the .NET version you're targeting, that's as important as the clarity of the question -- Why is PopulateData() marked async? There's nothing async there. If it's in a piece of code you have omitted, that method must return Task, not void. Also, show where you're awaiting it

Make the SolidBrush variable a field of your class. And use the TextChanged event, in which you change the color depending on the value
private SolidBrush solidBrush;

private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, 0, 0, 30, 30);
}

private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(label1.Text =="1")
        solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
    else
        solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
}

